# Exclude Cookies from Requests

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

Is it possible prevent some cookies to be sent to the server?

I have cookies that are set in JavaScript and only required on the client (to share data with other browser windows). I don't want them to be sent to the server.

Comment: Perhaps use local storage instead? Otherwise I don't think this is possible (without using multiple domains, which has its own set of issues).

Comment: I might have to look into that. The advantage of cookies is that they are supported everywhere.

Comment: just store the cookie, but set its "path" to an inexistent folder on the server. Not sure if this works (a trick)